# Send argument to console app and get string array in return

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, parameters

I am sending email body to the console application as parameter, the thing is I only see first 4 characters `<div` on the console application what happens to the other part? Can I send html email text as parameter to console application? Also is there any way to return a string[] array from console app?

My so far code below:

`TestingConsoleApp` to check the send n receive:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        string emailBody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\ehsankayani\Desktop\email1Html.txt");
        CallProcess(emailBody);
}

static void CallProcess(string body)
{
       string path = @"F:\Scrappers\emailParser_app\emailParser_app\bin\Debug\emailParser_app.exe";
       Process.Start(path, body);
}
```

Main console app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            Console.WriteLine("EMAIL BODY = ");
            string[] dataToReturn = new string[8];
            //string emailBody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\ehsankayani\Desktop\email1Html.txt");
            string emailBody = args[0];
            Console.WriteLine(emailBody);
            Console.WriteLine(emailBody.Length);
            Console.ReadLine();
            var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(emailBody);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simply HttpUtility.EncodeHtml(Emailbody) while sending and HttpUtility.DecodeHtml(emailBody) on receiving does the job.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing body as the parameter set in CallProcess. So if body were eg

```
xxxx yyyy ....
```

then args[0] would be just xxxx. You'll need to put "" around the text and escape in "'s in the text too.

A far better solution though would be to set up your Process to redirect stdin and to write the body to the process' stdin. This will avoid issues with whitespace and quotes. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx for details on doing this.

Comment: Yes you are right adding "" around the body works but it break on a ; ..Not sure what you mean by "Process to redirect stdin and to write the body to the process' stdin"?

Comment: Updated my answer to provide a link that explains how to do stdin/stdout redirection for a process.

Comment: using HtmlDecodeand n HtmlEncode works fine too , but does not work when i HtmlEncode on input and send it to the mainapp it does not convert write on HtmlDecode.However if i put it on the same app as a test it converts fine any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask for suggestions: For complex and/or large data, I'd rather pass only the information where to find the data to the process being called. Same can be done for returned data

This has several positive effects, the more complex and the larger these data are: You don't have to make sure the data are matching the command line restrictions, you don't have to allocate lots of memory to encode/decode the data in both processes, and you don't need to implement the logic to do that. Instead, write the data into a file, a shared memory region (MMF) or the like and pass that address.

Nearly the only downside is that you have to think about who's responsible for cleaning up.

Another possible approach could involve interprocess communication, but I think that's a bit overkill here.